# How to Fetch Data And Update data using Direct Sql query in phtml file In Magento 2.1.3?

Tags: magento2, database, query

How to Fetch Update data using Direct Sql query in phtml file In Magento 2.1.3..

Comment: It's a bad idea to execute SQL directly in a view file, it would be better to fetch needed data in block class via some service or model, and call block method in the view file.

Comment: I don't know who down vote my answer. Some developer want's to know how to do that but they don't use it.

Comment: Suppose, it's a bad practice to give answers on obviously the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$sql = 'select * from customer_grid_flat';
$data = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
```

**NB**: Always call block method and DI for creating model/repository object for 
fetching data.